# allowing house ads only on admob

Tags: admob

I'm trying to create a campaign on one of my apps using admob,
during the campaign i want it to display a certain interstitial ad (image) and **ONLY THAT**.

No matter what i try, i can't prevent admob from displaying their network ads, 
i've been trying to set eCPM really high (hoping it would give priority)
and i tried to selectively choose ALL countries for AdMob network and give them low value
i honestly tried everything i can find but couldn't solve this no matter what.

does any one have *any* idea ?

Comment: Have you tried giving AdMob ads really high eCPM in mediation and kept your house ads for $0.01 eCPM value?

Comment: @Kunalxigxag yes, and it did nothing. i honestly can't understand how a product backed by google and be so bad.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  The new Admob is a mess if you only want to display house ads.  Thanks.

Comment: @iTrout simply put ? there's no way to do it... 
i've since moved into a remotely hosted json based config file for ads, 
i set different different ratio and control all the ads networks externally (integrated on the app but conditionally being up/down according to the file)